# Use sed substitution from different files

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Okay, I am a newbie to Unix scripting. I was given the task to find a temporary work around for this:

```
cat /directory/filename1.xml |sed -e "s/ABCXYZ/${c}/g" > /directory/filename2.xml
```

$c is a variable from a sqlplus count query. I totally understand how this sed command is working. But here is where I am stuck. I am storing the count associated with the variable in another file called filename3 as count[$c] where $c is replaced with a number. So my question is how can I update this sed command to substitute ABCXYZ with the count from file3?

## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

UPDATE: In case anyone has a similar issue I got mine to work using:
rm /directory/folder/variablefilename.dat
echo $c >> /directory/folder/variablefilename.dat

d=$(grep [0-9] /directory/folder/variablefilename.dat)

sed -3 "s/ABC123/${d}/g" /directory/folder/inputfile.xml >> /directory/folder/outputfile.xml

thank you to Kaz for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Can you give an example of the contents of `filename3`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Please read even sooner about how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  In this context, the information missing is an illustration of the contents of your `filename3`.  The rest is fairly easily inferred, but a few lines of `filename1.xml` and the matching expected output in `filename2.xml` would not go amiss. Also note that there is no reason to use `cat` in this context; it is a [UUoC (Useless Use of `cat`)](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)

Answer (score 1):

Store the count in `filename3` using the syntax `c=number`. Then you can source the file as a shell script:

```
. /filename3 # get c variable
sed -e "s/ABCXYZ/${c}/g" /directory/filename1.xml > /directory/filename2.xml
```

If you can't change the format of `filename3`, you can write a shell function which scrapes the number out of that file and sets the `c` variable. Or you can scrape the number out with an external program like `grep`, and then interpolate its output into a variable assignment using command substitution: `$(command arg ...)` syntax.

Suppose we can rely on file3 to contain exactly one line of the form `count[42]`. Then we can just extract the digits with `grep -o`:

```
c=$(grep -E -o '[0-9]+' filename3)
sed -e "s/ABCXYZ/$c/g" /directory/filename1.xml > /directory/filename2.xml
```

The `c` variable can be eliminated, of course; you can stick the `$(grep ...)` into the `sed` command line in place of `$c`.

A file which contains numerous instances of syntax like `count[42]` for various variables could be transformed into a set of shell variable assignments using `sed`, and then sourced into the current shell to make those assignments happen:

```
$ sed -n -e 's/^\([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]\+\)\[\(.*\)\]/\1=\2/p' filename3 > vars.sh
$ . ./vars.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed the grep command slightly and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sed like this

```
sed -r "s/ABCXYZ/$(sed -nr 's/.*count[[]([0-9])+[]].*/\1/p' path_to_file)/g" path_to_file
```

the expression is double quoted which allow the shell to execute below and find the number in count[$c] in the file and use it as a substitute

```
$(sed -nr 's/.*count[[]([0-9])+[]].*/\1/p' path_to_file)
```